# Is it legal for a store to lock the door with customers inside?

Tags: canada, labor-law, british-columbia

In a retail store the manager has instructed employees to lock the door when the store has closed, even if customers are still inside. This is to prevent more customers from entering. Is locking the door with customers inside legal? To be clear it is an ordinary lock with the non key side being on the inside (i.e. the customers could let themselves out).

Who would handle such complaints?

Comment: Just curious why do you think it might be not legal? (Assuming the door and lock are fire code compliant) You should ask separate questions separately.

Comment: The second question may be related but it's still a separate question. You have a few hundred rep so I doubt anything's stopping you posting it separately.

Comment: If the customers can let themselves out, why would it be illegal?

Comment: That seems to be pretty common practice, I've certainly have seen that done.

Comment: @xngtng I'm not sure how the relevant laws are worded but I would imagine it's a blanket statement like "a person must not restrict another person's access from leaving". I guess unlocking the door is trivial, but it would be different if someone tried to defend "the room had a latter and a window they could have climbed through"

Comment: @casablancaeggplant What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @casablancaeggplant the question says that the locked door does not restrict anyone from leaving, so any law that does prevent such a restriction _would not apply to the locking of this door._

Answer (score 5):

The customers are able to leave, so there's no reason it could be a crime. Even if they weren't able to operate the lock themselves, they are presumably able to leave by asking a staff member. There is no way this could be remotely considered false imprisonment.

Depending on the layout and size of the store and presence/lack of other fire exits, this might violate fire safety regulations.

Answer (score -1):

In at least dorm jurisdictions, laws require be unlocked while customers are inside. This is a safety issue, so that peoplke wioll nort be trapped inside in the event of a fire or other emergency. Such laws were in many cases inspired by the [Triangle Shirtwaist Factory fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_Shirtwaist_Factory_fire) in New York City, in 1911. In that case exit doors were locked, and some 146 workers died in the fire.

The Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) Places restrictions on door locks in commercial buildings, so that disabled customers are able to exit safely. See '"Door Lock Compliance"](https://www.gvlock.com/blog/door-lock-compliance/) There are also OSHA requirements on this issue. See ["This Door Must Remain Unlocked. Why?"](https://www.pittalaw.com/blog/2017/05/this-door-must-remain-unlocked-why/)

To prevent additional would-be customers from entering, a business can station an employee at the door.

Comment: The question, at least as currently edited, notes that the doors are only locked from the outside direction. People in the store can get out.